# PHP parsing error while validating html form?

Tags: php

I have HTML form which I use together with PHP. Just before the email gets sent, I want the form to be validated by PHP. This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['yourName'];
    $email = $_POST['yourMail'];
    $message = $_POST['yourMessage'];
    $to = "blablabla@gmail.com";
    $subject = "New mail from bla-bla.org";
    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";


    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST") {
   $valid = true;

   if (empty($_POST["yourName"])) {
      $firstNameErr = "First name is required";
      $valid = false; //false
   }
   else {
      $firstName = test_input($_POST["yourName"]);
   }
   if (empty($_POST["yourMail"])) {
      $lastNameErr = "Last name is required";
      $valid = false;
   }
   else {
      $lastName = test_input($_POST["yourMail"]);
   }

   if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
        header("Location: http://www.blabla.org/contact.html");
    }

?>
```

After I click the `Send` button, I get this line in my browser:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/website/public_html/acknowledge.php on line 32

I went through my code over and over again, and cannot seem to find any mistake. Any suggestions or fresh pair of eyes that could suggest what is wrong?

**EDIT**: The parsing error is solved because of missing `}`. But, empty e-mails are still being sent without actual validation from PHP.

Comment: Missing `}` from the first `if`.

Comment: @Xufox Thank you, but the form still sends empty e-mails without validation...

Comment: That wasn't your question though. Nothing happens when you have a parse error. Were you getting emails previously?

Comment: @chris85 Yes I was getting. And, now I'm getting also, but I want the form to be validated because those empty e-mails are so annoying!:)

Comment: You aren't do anything when there is invalid input. Maybe `if (!empty($valid) && mail($to, $subject, $body)) {`

Comment: When you do `$valid = false;` you do nothing to stop the `mail` from executing.

Comment: @chris85 Urrrgghh, thanks Chris! Can't believe I missed that!